# How can I contain my text to stay inside the card without changing all my or html to much?

Tags: html, css

I do not want to use anything except css and html. What can be changed to fix the text from coming outside of the card? My text keeps overflowing outside of my card. I want it all to fit in without compromising the card size as well. I have tried resizing. I am also new to coding. I would accept all and any feedback. If you have links or videos please share those also.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
}

/* Header Start */
#vanta-canvas {
width: 100vw;
height: 50vh;
}

.inner_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
}

.flex {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-content: normal;
}

header p {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    font-family: cursive;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.highlight {
color: blue;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 45% 3px; 
    color: #b4b4b4;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

button:hover, button:focus{
    background-color: grey;
    color: blue;
}

button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
}

button:hover span:after{
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}
/* Header End */

/* navigation Start */
nav {
    background: blue;
    border-bottom: solid 2px;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Navigation End */

/* Section About Start */
section {
    box-align: center;
}
section h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    /* border-bottom: solid 3px; */
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%)
}

section h2::after {
    content:"";
    height: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000000;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

section p {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;

}
/* Section About End */
/* Section Portfolio Start */
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backgrace-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* @media screen and (max-width: 600px){ */
    /* .column {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en_US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" > 
</head>

    <body>
        <!-- Header Start -->
        <div id="vanta-canvas">
            <header>
                <h1 class="inner_header" class="flex" id="Home">
                    <p>
                     Hello, I'm&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span class="highlight">Brian Mojica.</span> 
                    <br>
                    I'm a full-stack web developer.
                    <button class="flex" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>
                    View My Work
                    </span></button>
                    </p>
                </h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        </header>
        <!--Header End-->
        <!-- Navigation Start -->
       <nav>
           <ul>
               <li> 
                    <a href="#Home">HOME</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#About">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#Portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#Blog">BLOG</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#Contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PeP8jPx4ct_WFCPPNeYYgJaiSRx9p8il5QjwZ7s0wbQ/edit?usp=sharing" target="_blank">RESUME</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </nav>
       <!--Navigation End-->
       <!--Section About-->
       <section>
           <h2 id="About">ABOUT</h2>
                <p>
                    I'm a full stack developer seeking employment. 
                    I have a passion developing webpages that are responsive, dynamic, and accessbile. 
                    Animations and UI effects are skills I hope to sharpen. I will continually expand my knowledge in different platforms such as Python, JavaScript, and React.
                </p>
        </section>
       <!--Section Portfolio-->
       <section>
           <h2 id="Portfolio">PORTFOLIO</h2>
                <div class="flip-card">
                    <div class="flip-card-inner">
                        <div class="flip-card-front">
                            <a href="https://brainybrian316.github.io/run-buddy/"></a>
                            <img src="assets/images/run-buddy-card.png" alt="Webpage" style="width:100%" height="100%">
                        </div>
                        <div class="flip-card-back">
                            <h1>Run Buddy</h1>
                            <p class="highlight"> HTML / CSS</p>
                            <p>A webpage for Run Buddy. They are a  company that matches runners with personal trainers. </p>
                            <button class="flex" style="vertical-align:middle"><span> View</span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
        
    
       </section>
       <!--Section Blog-->
       <section>
           <h2 id="Blog">BLOG</h2>
                <p>Under Construction</p>
       </section>
       <!--Section Contact-->
       <section>
           <h2 id="Contact">CONTACT</h2>
       </section>
       <!--Section Resume-->
       <section>
           <a id="resume" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVWXW7AULRBQBeXEblFfHNawPX-pHrJC/view?usp=sharing"></a>
       </section>



       <!--script for header background Start-->
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r121/three.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanta@latest/dist/vanta.waves.min.js"></script>
       <script>
           VANTA.WAVES({
            el: "#vanta-canvas",
           mouseControls: true,
            touchControls: true,
           gyroControls: false,
           minHeight: 100.00,
           minWidth: 100.00,
           scale: 1.00,
           scaleMobile: 1.00,
           color: 0x102
            })
       </script>
       <!--script for header background End-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: scroll` properties in the `.flip-card-back` class to either hide the content that isn't fitting or make it scrollable. You should also keep in mind the size of the content, it's too much for the card's dimensions. Styling properly the text inside the card would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code. Please check. the important point is to use `font-size: 6vmin` in here for `#vanta-canvas`. I used that instead of `h1`. It causes a font-size based on screen size.

**Note:** https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #b4b4b4;
}


/* Header Start */

#vanta-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 6vmin; /* here */
}

.inner_header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-content: normal;
}

.inner_header p {
  color: #b4b4b4;
  font-family: cursive;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.highlight {
  color: blue;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 45% 3px;
  color: #b4b4b4;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
  background-color: grey;
  color: blue;
}

button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


/* Header End */


/* navigation Start */

nav {
  background: blue;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Navigation End */


/* Section About Start */

section {
  box-align: center;
}

section h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  /* border-bottom: solid 3px; */
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

section h2::after {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

section p {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Section About End */


/* Section Portfolio Start */

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backgrace-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* @media screen and (max-width: 600px){ */


/* .column {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
} */
```

```html
<!-- Header Start -->
<div id="vanta-canvas">
  <div class="inner_header" class="flex" id="Home">
    <p>
      Hello, I'm&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="highlight">Brian Mojica.</span>
      <br> I'm a full-stack web developer.
      <button class="flex" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>
                    View My Work
                    </span></button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<!--Header End-->
<!-- Navigation Start -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#Home">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#About">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Blog">BLOG</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Contact">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PeP8jPx4ct_WFCPPNeYYgJaiSRx9p8il5QjwZ7s0wbQ/edit?usp=sharing" target="_blank">RESUME</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!--Navigation End-->
<!--Section About-->
<section>
  <h2 id="About">ABOUT</h2>
  <p>
    I'm a full stack developer seeking employment. I have a passion developing webpages that are responsive, dynamic, and accessbile. Animations and UI effects are skills I hope to sharpen. I will continually expand my knowledge in different platforms such
    as Python, JavaScript, and React.
  </p>
</section>
<!--Section Portfolio-->
<section>
  <h2 id="Portfolio">PORTFOLIO</h2>
  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <a href="https://brainybrian316.github.io/run-buddy/"></a>
        <img src="assets/images/run-buddy-card.png" alt="Webpage" style="width:100%" height="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h1>Run Buddy</h1>
        <p class="highlight"> HTML / CSS</p>
        <p>A webpage for Run Buddy. They are a company that matches runners with personal trainers. </p>
        <button class="flex" style="vertical-align:middle"><span> View</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Section Blog-->
<section>
  <h2 id="Blog">BLOG</h2>
  <p>Under Construction</p>
</section>
<!--Section Contact-->
<section>
  <h2 id="Contact">CONTACT</h2>
</section>
<!--Section Resume-->
<section>
  <a id="resume" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVWXW7AULRBQBeXEblFfHNawPX-pHrJC/view?usp=sharing"></a>
</section>

<!--script for header background Start-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r121/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanta@latest/dist/vanta.waves.min.js"></script>
<script>
  VANTA.WAVES({
    el: "#vanta-canvas",
    mouseControls: true,
    touchControls: true,
    gyroControls: false,
    minHeight: 100.00,
    minWidth: 100.00,
    scale: 1.00,
    scaleMobile: 1.00,
    color: 0x102
  })
</script>
<!--script for header background End-->
```

**On larger screen size:**

[image]

**On smaller screen size:**

[image]

Comment: wow thank you for providing the screen shots this looks awesome.

Comment: @BrianMojica you're welcome brian. I hope it is useful.